# Getting error to open the file through service account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET treeview controls and mentioning direct file server path inside the NavigateURL.

We have a new service account and has mapped with the file server folder and it's ready for accessible (it's working fine).

When accessing through application, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find "\USA\NYK\EMPDB\EMPDETAILS\EMP00101.drng" Make sure the path or Internet address is correct

The same folder will work when accessing through physical login of service account.

We did all the settings and configuration followed by many research. but, not able to get the solution..?

Please advice.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" 
     ExpandDepth="1" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="15px" 
     ForeColor="#E98300" Font-Bold="true">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="EmpStatus" Value="EmpStatus">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="USEMP" Value="USEMP">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="EMPUS" Value="EMPUS" NavigateUrl="\\USA\NYK\EMPDB\EMPDETAILS\EMP00101.drng" Target="_blank"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" 
          userName="DUENET\DATAPM1010" password ="**"></identity>
```

Full server path : \USA\NYK\EMPDB\EMPDETAILS\EMP00101.drng.

Application located in one server, and accessing file is located on another file server.

Comment: Shouldn't it start with 2 slashes? Try adding a @ sign to start. NavigateURL=@"\\path\here"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, i am getting below error when i used @ symbol.                                      Error : validation (ASP.NET):If this attibute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.                                                                                                    NavigateUrl=@"\\USA\NYK\EMPDB\EMPDETAILS\EMP00101.drng" ==> Error in line.

Comment: can anyone update on this issue...? This is very urgent..

Comment: What account is IIS running on? Try checking iof that account has proper permissions to the location/folder.

Comment: Thanks for all your help..I'm logging service account and map to my system to refresh the account. it's working now.